# How to remove the element's event handler and set it back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JQuery and facing some problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/puzzle.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
            <a href="#" class="link1">link1</a>
            <a href="#" class="link2">link2</a>
            <a href="#" class="link3">link3</a>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>

$(
    function() {        
        $("#parent").on("click", "a", function() {
            linkClick(this);
        });

        function linkClick(link) {            
            $("#parent a").first().off("click");
            console.log(link);
        }
    }
)
```

Question1: When the user clicks one of the links, can I remove the link's event haneler?

Question2: If the Question1 has been soled, can I add the  onclick event handler back to "the specified link" without affecting other links?

Thanks for your reading.

==

I tried to use **$("#parent a").first().off("click");** to unbind the first link's event handler.
But no matter how many times I click the first link, this console still prints data.

How do I remove the link's event handler and then add it back in a few seconds???

Answer (score 0):

Use `off`

Remove event:

```
$( "#parent a").first().off( "click" );
```

Add Event:

```
$( "#parent a").first().on( "click", function(){
   //click event code
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 //Remove click event for first element

 $( "#parent a").first().off("click");

 //Bind new event to element:

 $( "#parent a").first().bind('click',function(){
  //click event code
 })
```

Comment: Thanks.Using "on" and "off" instead of "bind" and "unbind" is always a good practise.

Comment: Sorry, I have revised my problem.
If it is not the first link but specified by users(randomly picked), how do i do?

Comment: what is the problem now. Use nth child selctor instead of first for doing same with other anchor tag.

Comment: So...when the user clicked the link, I have to find the links's position and turn it off, like this?

$( "#parent a").eq(nth).off("click");